# Placing text (numbers) at indicated positions

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

With a for-loop I iterate over a set of coordinates stored in matrix X, and draw circles at indicated positions (itextpdf used):

```
...
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fileName));

Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, new PageSize(one));

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {   

    canvas.circle(X[d * i + axisX], X[d * i + axisY], 1.0);
    canvas.fillStroke();
    // -- numbers (i+1) should be drawn beside the circles

}
```

How could I use the above for-loop and write the numbers beside the circles, as indicated above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to add text at absolute positions with iText 7.

Since you already have a `PdfCanvas` object, you can use the very low-level approach that consists of writing PDF syntax line by line:

```
canvas.beginText();
canvas.moveText(x, y);
canvas.showText("1");
canvas.endText();
```

This is explained in [chapter 3 of the iText 7 jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-2-adding-low-level-content).

Writing low-level PDF syntax is error-prone when you don't know the PDF reference by heart. There is also an easier way:

```
document.showTextAligned(new Paragraph("1"), x, y, TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

Now you don't have to worry about constructing a text object using `beginText()` and `endText()`; iText takes care of all the low-level syntax.

This is explained in [chapter 2 of the building blocks tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the first suggestion, and now I have the "font.and.size.must.be.set.before.writing.any.text" exception. I tried "PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.CP1250, true);", but this gives a bunch of errors. I would appreciate a min example.